# Big Query - How to expand value in a column per company to populate all null values in that column per company with an existing value?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with a table that looks like this (query to duplicate this table in your environment is provided at the bottom):

```
--------------------------------------------------       
id  |   timestamp_page_view  |   timestamp_signup

1       2021-04-17 17:01:00                                    
1       2021-04-16 14:31:00
1       2021-04-14 21:13:00
1       2021-04-13 11:15:00
1       2021-04-12 14:57:00    2021-04-12 14:59:00
1       2021-04-09 11:33:00
1       2021-04-05 14:44:00
1       2021-03-31 17:12:00

2       2021-03-31 17:13:00
2       2021-03-31 12:45:00    2021-03-31 12:45:00
2       2021-03-30 04:14:00
2       2021-03-29 19:47:00
2       2021-03-28 17:16:00
2       2021-03-27 14:00:00

3       2021-03-18 18:18:00
3       2021-03-03 15:54:00
3       2021-02-27 21:44:00
3       2021-03-13 13:14:00
3       2021-03-12 12:56:00

4       2021-03-30 17:17:00
4       2021-04-18 14:14:00
4       2021-04-19 14:50:00    2021-04-19 14:54:00
4       2021-04-20 17:18:00
4       2021-03-30 15:56:00
4       2021-03-03 09:18:00
4       2021-03-29 10:10:00
```

In my dummy table, `timestamp_signup` is only present on 1 row per id (it is present on a row that shows an online session during which a company signed up). If a company never signed up, there is no `timestamp_signup` value.

What I am trying to do is to calculate

- How many page views each team has in total
- How many page views does each team have before a team signed up (timestamp_page_view <= timestamp_signup)

My desired output will look like this, based on dummy data provided:

```
 id     total_views     views_before_signup
    
    1          4                   8
    2          5                   6
    3          0                   5
    4          6                   7
```

The way I know to calculate this - which won't get me my result - is:

```
 SELECT id,
        COUNT(timestamp_page_view) AS total_views, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN timestamp_page_view <= timestamp_signup THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS views_before_signups,
FROM table_1 
GROUP BY id
```

There are 2 problems with the way I know to calculate this:

- timestamp_signup is not present for each timestamp_page_view event
- companies that never signed up will not be in the output of my query

I was thinking of a way to expand `timestamp_signup` to all rows per company where there is a `timestamp_signup` for a company, but I don't know how to do this, after doing research. This would also help me then identify which companies never signed up.

Question to you:

- With the way the dummy data sits (without expanding `timestamp_signup` values) is there a way to get to my desired result? If not,
- What query would help me expand `timestamp_signup` to all rows per company?

Script to recreate dummy data in your environment:

```
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-17 17:01:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-16 14:31:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-14 21:13:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-13 11:15:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-12 14:57:00' AS timestamp_page_view, '2021-04-12 14:59:00' AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-09 11:33:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-05 14:44:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-03-31 17:12:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-31 17:13:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-31 12:45:00' AS timestamp_page_view, '2021-03-31 12:45:00' AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-30 04:14:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-29 19:47:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-28 17:16:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-27 14:00:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-18 18:18:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-03 15:54:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-02-27 21:44:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-13 13:14:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-12 12:56:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-30 17:17:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-04-18 14:14:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-04-19 14:50:00' AS timestamp_page_view, '2021-04-19 14:54:00' AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-04-20 17:18:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-30 15:56:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-03 09:18:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-29 10:10:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-17 17:01:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-16 14:31:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-14 21:13:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-13 11:15:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-12 14:57:00' AS timestamp_page_view, '2021-04-12 14:59:00' AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-09 11:33:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-04-05 14:44:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2021-03-31 17:12:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-31 17:13:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-31 12:45:00' AS timestamp_page_view, '2021-03-31 12:45:00' AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-30 04:14:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-29 19:47:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-28 17:16:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2021-03-27 14:00:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-18 18:18:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-03 15:54:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-02-27 21:44:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-13 13:14:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS id, '2021-03-12 12:56:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-30 17:17:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-04-18 14:14:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-04-19 14:50:00' AS timestamp_page_view, '2021-04-19 14:54:00' AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-04-20 17:18:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-30 15:56:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-03 09:18:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS id, '2021-03-29 10:10:00' AS timestamp_page_view, NULL AS timestamp_signup
)
select 
  id,
  countif(future_signup is not null) as views_before_signup,
  count(*) as total_views
from (
  select 
    *,
    max(timestamp_signup) over (partition by id order by timestamp_page_view desc) as future_signup
  from mytable
)
group by id
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. I will break down your answer so I can learn from your knowledge. Please consider upvoting this question if you believe it is helpful to the community and is well written